# Monitoring MIDI Input from external Roland A-500PRO Controller

Tags: midi, cubase, usb

I'm trying to make a [Roland A-500PRO](http://www.roland.com/products/en/A-500PRO/) USB MIDI Controller work with Steinberg's [Cubase LE AI Elements 6](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/cubase/start.html) for Windows. By default, except the 49 keyboard keys, *none* of the other sliders, knobs or transport controls work.

I'm able to play and record songs with the Roland A-500PRO keys but I have to use the computer keyboard and mouse for starting and stopping the recording, or changing the volume of a track for instance, which is *very* frustrating.

The Roland A-500PRO has the concept of a *Control Map* which is designed to send specific MIDI messages when using a specific controller. It comes with a simple to use software editor in order to customize an existing or create a new *Control Map* from scratch.

I would like to be able to use this editor to customize the Roland A-500PRO so that it works with Cubase, but I figure I would have two strategies.

1. Either customize the Roland A-500PRO *Control Map* in order to produce MIDI messages as expected by Cubase...
2. Or, instruct Cubase to trigger the desired function when receiving specific MIDI messages from the Roland A-500 PRO controller.

In order to do that I would like to monitor the MIDI messages sent by the Roland A-500PRO controller when pressing specific keys or using specific controls. However, I have been unable to find a way to do that.

I'm aware of several MIDI monitoring software but I could not make any of these work.

- [Midi Test](http://earthvegaconnection.com/evc/products/miditest/index.html) : this software simple does not work. It simply fails with a "MIDI no properly initialized" message, even though MIDI works perfectly well with Cubase.
- [Midi Monitor](http://obds.free.fr/midimon/indexfr.htm) : this software is hard to understand. It ran once and successfully detected the Roland A-500PRO input and output MIDI ports, but I did not manage to use it. Now, it fails to run with a "Unable to create C:\windows\System32\WINMM174.SYS" message.
- [MidiOX](http://midiox.com/index.htm) : this software sounds like the best bet but I'm unable to make it produce MIDI message when using the Roland A-500PRO controller.

Please, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Related: http://avp.stackexchange.com/q/4964/2569 Looks like a couple of those suggestions are ones that you've tried unsuccessfully.  There's a third there too.  Never used it myself...

Comment: MidiOX is the way to go.  If that isn't working, your controller isn't sending messages.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely like to make MidiOX working. Cubase does receive MIDI note events out of the box, though so I guess I just need help configuring MidiOX. Is there some tutorial somewhere. I might be simply missing something obvious but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question since I finally figured out what went wrong.

The Roland A-500PRO controller exposes three MIDI ports :

1. MIDI IN
2. PRO1 IN
3. PRO2 IN

MIDI messages from the controller are, by default, split between ports PRO1 IN and PRO2 IN. Note messages as well as Pitch Bend and Modulation messages go through the PRO1 IN port. All other control change messages go through PRO2 IN port.

As far as MIDIOX is concerned, no messages go through the MIDI IN port, so I had o select either one of the PRO1 IN or PRO2 IN ports, or both. Although, in practice - for Cubase or, I suspect, other DAWs - the MIDI IN port is a combination of the other two ports.

Comment: Please check out this [SO blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) for information on when to use the wiki status.  An exerpt:  The intent of community wiki in answers is to help share the burden of solving a question. An incomplete “seed” answer is a stepping stone to a complete solution with help from others; an incomplete question is a hindrance and an obstacle to getting a solution as no one understands the inquiry. It is in answers that the goal of community wiki, for the community, by the community, shows its truest colors.